# Oracle - multiple select count from different tables

Tags: oracle, join

I need to get information out of 3 different tables which are somewhat linked like table1 -> table2 -> table3

the problem is that i need to count a specific column in table2 & table3. for table2 alone it works just as intended, but as soon as i throw table3 in the same way i did with table2, id changes the count of table2 to the count of table3 (which itself is right)

the code look like that

```
select 1.ID, 1.SomeMoreInformation, count(2.ID), count(3.ID) 
from 1 
join 2 on 1.ID = 2.whatever 
join 3 on 3.ID = 2.something
group by 1.ID, 1.SomeMoreInformation
order by 1.ID
```

as you can see the ID of table1 is in table2 -> i need to know how often for each table1.ID
and of all these entries in table2 i need to know how many of them are in table3, using another column

result as of the moment:

```
1.id | 2.count | 3.count
1    | x       | x
```

instead of:

```
1.id | 2.count | 3.count
1    | x       | y
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the `DISTINCT` while counting the number of ID's as follows:

```
SELECT
    1.ID,
    1.SOMEMOREINFORMATION,
    COUNT(DISTINCT 2.ID), 
    count(DISTINCT 3.ID) 
from 1 left join 2 on 1.ID = 2.whatever 
       left join 3 on 3.ID = 2.something
group by 1.ID, 1.SOMEMOREINFORMATION 
ORDER BY 1.ID;
```

If `2.ID` record maps to multiple records from table 3 then there will be multiple records for single `2.ID` and multiple `3.ID`. Hence, using DISTINCT will give you proper information.

Comment: unfortunatly this results in the same output. Just for clarification:
3 contains entries from 2, each entry from 2 can only be found once or not at all in 3

Comment: sample data and expected output will help us here

Answer (score 0):

```
table1            table2                                           table3
ID                  ID      | whatever     | something             ID        
--------            --------| ------------ | --------------        --------- 
123                321      |  123         |  1a2b                  1a2b   
                   654      |  123         |  3c4d                 5e6f
```

expected would be

count 2.id = 2

count 3.id = 1

it is

count 2.id = 1

count 3.id = 1

Comment: Why count 2.id should be 2? it has only 1 matching record

Comment: My answer must be giving the same answer which is expected. i.e. `count2.id = 2` and `count3.id = 1`

Comment: for me the output still seems to be the same.




whenever the entry from 2 has no match in 3, it does not count in count(distinct 2.id).


this also results in 1.id not being shown at all if no entry is found in 3.id that results to be linked to 1.id, despite there being entries in table2 linked to 1.id

Comment: Then you can use the LEFT JOIN as updated in my original answer